# Search for list of integers within another list C#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I would like to find all the occurances of my source list in my dictionary.

Currently, I'm looping through my dictionary, and comparing each value of dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, list<int>> refList.
List<int> sourceList.

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> kvp in refDict)
{
  List<int> refList = (List<int>)kvp.Value;
  bool isMatch = (refList.Count == sourceList.Count && refList.SequenceEqual(sourceList));
  if (isMatch)
  {
     ......
     ......
  }
}
```

I would like to find the indexes in my dict of all the occurances of my source list.

Comment: Sounds like a set intersection to me. Maybe you should be using HashSets instead of Lists?

Comment: I don't see a question. Your code looks complete.

Comment: Do you mean Dictionary<string, list<int>> refDict?

Comment: There's no real concept of "index" within a standard `Dicionary<TKey,TKValue>`, so I'm not sure I understand your question. However, there *is* the `OrderedDictionary` class. You may want to investigate that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx There's also `SortedDictionary`, which doesn't have *access* via index, but has a consistent order, so an item's place in the dictionary is predictable.

Comment: And are you looking for the indexes or the keys?

Comment: @Scott Rippey : as far as I understand hee need an `index` of item rather a key

Comment: Thank you all for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why you need a position (not an index!) of dictionary items because order of items is non deterministic, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as
>   a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its
>   key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

but anyways:

**Prepare data:**

```
IDictionary<string, List<int>> refDict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>
                                {
                                    {"item1", new List<int> {1, 2, 3}},
                                    {"item2", new List<int> {4, 5, 6}},
                                    {"item3", new List<int> {1, 2, 3}}
                                };
List<int> sourceList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
```

**Search for indexes:**

```
var indexes = refDict.Values
    .Select((list, index) => list.SequenceEqual(sourceList) ? index : -1)
    .Where(x => x >= 0);
```

**Search for keys:**

```
var keys = refDict
    .Where(item => item.Value.SequenceEqual(sourceList))
    .Select(item => item.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<int> { 1,2,3 };
var dico = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

dico.Add("A", list);
dico.Add("B", new List<int> { 2,3 });
dico.Add("C", new List<int> { 1,2,3 });

var keys = dico.Where (d => d.Value.SequenceEqual(list)).Select (d => d.Key);
```

Pay attention that this wil return "A" and "C" !!!